# Failed to start solana-test-validator on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana

When I try to run solana-test-validator , I get the following terminal output with error:

```
--faucet-sol argument ignored, ledger already exists
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Error: failed to start validator: TestValidator startup failed: Custom { kind: Other, error: "Discover failed" }
```

My `solana config get`:

```
Config File: /Users/wojciech/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://localhost:8899
WebSocket URL: ws://localhost:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /Users/wojciech/.config/solana/id.json
Commitment: confirmed
```

rustc versionL `rustc 1.58.0 (02072b482 2022-01-11)`

I've tried with both installation ways: recommended- via curl and I have also built and installed from source (both ver 1.9.4).
No errors or warnings during both installations.

Answer (score 2):

Build from source allows you functionality for both `solana-test-validator` and allows one to utilize the anchor environment to build and test. You can use `cargo build` and `cargo test` but that will not populate the `target/idl` with the proper artifacts needed.

*Note: You will need to run the command `solana-test-validator` from within your project directory once the symlink to the path is set. So if you're project is hello-world, you run the test-validator from there, not the Solana source files.*

In the below instructions, build-source refers to the Source code (tar.gz) file you download to follow the instructions to build from source in order to install the Solana CLI tools found here: https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#build-from-source

Go to `sdk/cargo-build-bpf` from the build-source project root. From there, run the following:

```sh
cargo install --path .
```

Verify the path created by opening a separate terminal and navigating to `~/.cargo/bin`. List the contents of bin with:

```sh
ln -l .
```

You will either see SDK or cargo-build-bpf. On my Mac M1 chip running Monterey, I found the path to end with the latter.

So, On an apple M1 chip the cargo-build-bpf program is installed to the path `~/.cargo/bin/cargo-build-bpf`. This will allow you to run commands like `anchor build` successfully in your local project root once you create a symlink from it to the path in your Solana source `code/bin/sdk` folder.

In a separate terminal navigate to `~/.cargo/bin` and create a symlink to the sdk folder in the build-source project’s bin folder, like this:

```sh
ln -s solana-1.9.2/bin/sdk ~/.cargo/bin/cargo-build-bpf
```

Replace `solana-1.9.2` with the build-source code you downloaded earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution also does not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the logs at `test-ledger/validator.log`. Usually it will be some ERROR message like

```
re^[[0m^[[38;5;8m]^[[0m On mac OS you may need to run |sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 500000 500000| first
```

Running `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 500000 500000` fixes it in many cases.